# Drag and Drop в Delphi

Tags: delphi, drag-n-drop

Всем привет, появилась необходимость перетаскивать элементы с Form1 на  Form2 к примеру перенести мышью текст с 1-й формы в Edit1 другой формы, возможно ли такое реализовать? И в какую сторону искать информацию? Я слышала про Drag and Drop, в инете полно примеров, но там перетаскивание файлов, а мне нужно из одного окна в другое и в нужный компонент, помогите с решением это проблемы!

Comment: https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/drag_and_drop_interface.html Посмотрите этот пример.

Comment: Этот пример я видела, я решила использовать хук на мышку, перехватить нажатую кнопку и перетаскивание, так как текст не переноситься за пределы формы, соответственно текст и не перебрасывается (( может кто помочь в этом ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [статья](https://delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/drag_and_drop_interface.html) с небольшим описанием механизма *Drag and Drop*.

Основные участи кода для элемента-источника `TFormFrom.EditFrom` (события `OnEndDrag`, `OnMouseDown`) и элемента-приемника `TFormTo.EditTo` (события `OnDragDrop`, `OnDragOver`)

```
procedure TFormFrom.EditFromEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(Target) then
    TEdit(Sender).Text := 'Текст перенесен в ' + TEdit(Target).Name;
end;

procedure TFormFrom.EditFromMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
    TEdit(Sender).BeginDrag(True);
end;

procedure TFormTo.EditToDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TEdit(Sender).Text := TEdit(Source).Text;
  TEdit(Sender).SetFocus;
  TEdit(Sender).SelectAll;
end;

procedure TFormTo.EditToDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  if Source is TEdit then
    Accept := True
  else
    Accept := False;
end;
```